# Add a 7-8 minute delay to a predefined EPOCH time in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am getting a EPOC time from a remote machine, which is present in different timezone compare to the local system. I want to add a 7-8minute time to that EPOC time. Is there any way I can do this in powershell?

The EPOCH time is with `precision rfc3339`

For example, I have `current time 1641960490800` as time of the remote machine, I want to add 7-8 minutes to it and print it in the same format like `1641960817177`.

Couldn't find similar post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are relying on an application to deliver the time, you probably need to parse it before adding the time. Something like

```
precision rfc3339 |
    # parse the number out
    Select-String -Pattern '\d+' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
    # retrieves just the number
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value |
    # adds 8 minutes (*60seconds)
    # order is important so that it converts the string into a number type
    ForEach-Object {60*8 + $_}
```

Or, if that looks daunting there technically is a non-pipeline approach:

```
$(precision rfc3339) -Match '\d+'
60*8 + $Matches[1]
```

Personally, although it looks a bit more convoluted, I think PowerShell is the strongest when using its pipelines, but that is a matter of style/choice.